# Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Library -> Access Azure Key Vault -> Key Vault not allowing access from all networks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

We have set up a connection between Azure DevOps and Azure Key Vault via Service Connections (service principal authentication). However in order for it to work we need to have the `Azure Key Vault` -> `Networking` marked as Allow access from: `All networks`. Given that we store secrets here we would like to use the option `Private endpoint and selected networks` instead with `Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall?` set to `Yes`.

Like this:

[image]

However this results in the error on Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Library:

> The specified Azure service connection needs to have "Get, List"
>   secret management permissions on the selected key vault. Click
>   "Authorize" to enable Azure Pipelines to set these permissions or
>   manage secret permissions in the Azure portal.

[image]

If we set Allow access from: `All networks` for the Azure Key Vault it works as previously stated but we would like to avoid this if possible.

[image]

Setting up an Azure Key Vault Task in Pipeline

[image]

or setting up an Variable group and then switching back to `Private endpoint and selected networks` results in a similar error on deploy.

[image]

> MyKey: "Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted
>   service.\r\nClient address: 111.222.333.44\r\nCaller:
>   appid=***;oid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;iss=https://sts.windows.net/***/\r\nVault:
>   My-Vault;location=northeurope. The specified Azure service connection
>   needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected
>   key vault. To set these permissions, download the
>   ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and
>   execute it, or set them from the Azure portal."

[image]

Client address is unfortunately new every time as expected but `oid` and `iss` values are the same. According to documentation only `IPv4 address or CIDR` can be added to the Firewall. Is there any way to mark Azure Agents as trusted Microsoft services or is this a bad practice? It does seem way safer than `All networks` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is still an open issue - [Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38914)

Probably some of the solutions are as mentioned in the URL

- add a task in your pipeline and whitelist IP of your agent and then once you have the values from keyvault remove th whitelist.
- WhiteList Azure DevOps IP list weekly maybe but again that seems unreliable
- What @Grand suggested is also one of the solutions actually.

Answer (score 1):

*(Update after author comment)*

Are you using Microsoft hosted agents? They are being dynamic, maybe you could host agent on a vm in Azure instead. You will know IP of the machine and allow it in KV settings.

Check out [Self-Hosted Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)
 in Microsoft docs.

Comment: We are using `service principal authentication`, clarified that in original question. We do however need to access Azure Key Vault from an unknown IP-adress and from what I can tell this is the problem we are facing. Service Principal has access but the IP it is used from is not allowed.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft hosted agents? Maybe you could host agent on a vm in Azure instead. You will know IP of the machine and allow it in KV settings. Check out `Self-hosted agents` in microsoft docs.

Answer (score 0):

I went for the whitelist IP approach.
Since, the IPs get updated weekly. I created two pipelines that run weekly. One to add the IP and 2nd to remove the IPs.

I've added the Azure CLI task in the pipeline and added the following lines:

```
Write-Host "Retrieve IPs for <region>"
$aeServiceTags =  az network list-service-tags --location australiaeast | ConvertFrom-Json
$aeRegion = $aeServiceTags.Values | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'AzureCloud.<add the region name>'}
$aeIps = $aeRegion.Properties.AddressPrefixes

Write-Host "Filter by IPv4"
$aeIps = $aeIps | ? { $_ -match '([0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*)[.]([0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*)[.]([0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*)[.]([0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*)[/][0-9]+' }

Write-Host "Adding the IP for the associated key vault"
az keyvault network-rule add --name "<key vault name>" --ip-address $aeIps
```

At the end of the pipeline, I delete the same IP to make sure it's updated

```
Write-Host "Retrieve the current IP for this key vault"
$buildIP = az keyvault network-rule list --name  "<key vault name>" | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host "Remove the current IP for the associated key vault"
az keyvault network-rule remove --name "<key vault name>" --ip-address $buildIP.ipRules.value
```

*Make sure the service connection is setup first

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and looks like this is still an open item for Azure Team.

**Issue:** Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Library -> Access Azure Key Vault  throwed error: "Specified Azure service connection needs to have "Get, List" secret management permissions on the selected key vault."
[image]

**P.S.:** The service principal has given contributor access through RBAC and secret "Get", "List" permission using Access policy.

**Cause:** I have identified that this issue is due to the public access disabled configuration at Key Vault network setting.

**Solution:** Whitelisting the respective regional Devops service IP Address. Bur for this solution to work we need tp update the Key Vault firewall configuration "Allow Public access from specific virtual network and IP Address".

[image]
[image]